# JPA entity inheritance without additional tables

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, jpa

I am working on a Maven Java web project based on Spring, JPA and Hibernate.

One part of this project shall be reused in another very similar project and gets therefore extracted as Maven module. This service and the corresponding entity are annotated like this:

```
@Service
public class MessageService

@Entity
public class Message
```

Both projects have similar but slightly different UserEntities.

```
@Entity
public class TypeAUser
@Entity
public class TypeBUser
```

The Message Entity has @OneToMany relationship to one of the UserEntities in each project.

I thought about a generic UserEntity but want to avoid creating additional tables as well as tables with fields of the "other" project.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Best regards,
Stefan

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to create additional tables, then you might want to consider using [SINGLE_TABLE strategy.](http://javajee.com/single-table-inheritance-strategy-in-hibernate)

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class UserEntity {
...
}

@Entity
public class TypeAUser extends UserEntity {
...
}

@Entity
public class TypeBUser extends UserEntity {
...
}
```

Comment: Well I don't want them do have the same identity nor the same table as those are two separate projects with two separate databases just sharing this one maven module.

Answer (score 1):

Well, when talking about Inheritance in Hibernate, you have three options:

1. Table per concrete class with unions
2. Table per class hierarchy(Single Table Strategy)
3. Table per subclass

Since you want to achieve it with one table, I suggest using option 2.

You need just a User table, with a USER_TYPE column to discriminate the user types ( Can be a  number, varchar2, etc)

Then you need to create a class **User** with the following annotations:
You can specify a DiscriminatorColumn if you want, otherwise Hibernate will default to `'{className}_TYPE`

`@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE) 
 @DiscriminatorColumn(name="USER_TYPE", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
 public class User { .... }`

In your concrete class implementations you can specify a Discriminator value (or if you don't, hibernate will default it to the class name `('TypeAUser'/ 'TypeBUser')`

`@Entity
 @DiscriminatorValue('A')
 public class TypeAUser
 @Entity
 @DiscriminatorValue('B')
 public class TypeBUser`

Comment: Just a note. `@DiscriminatorColumn` and `@DiscriminatorValue` are not required annotations (but it is good to have them). If the superclass entity is named User, then it's discriminator column will be `USER_TYPE`, which will be of type String. `@DiscriminatorValue` will default to `'TypeAUser'` and `'TypeBUser'`.

Comment: oh, ok, nice to know! I edited my answer based on your comment. Thank you!